# Strange characters appended to node name with XML DataContractSerializer

Tags: xml, serialization, asp.net-web-api, datacontractserializer

I'm using ASP.NET Web API to serve out the following class

```
public class MyListDataContract<T> : List<MyObjectDataContract<T>> where T : MyDataContract
```

I'm using `DataContractAttribute` on this specific `T` and `DataMemberAttribute` on the instance of this property.

The XML representation of this becomes

```
<MyObjectDataContractRvPTQ4uA>
...
</MyObjectDataContractRvPTQ4uA>
<MyObjectDataContractRvPTQ4uA>
....
</MyObjectDataContractRvPTQ4uA>
.
.
```

I have no idea what would be causing this, maybe a naming conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928069/wcf-serialised-list-object-giving-strange-names-for-objects) the serializer is trying to enforce uniqueness.

Forcing the `DataContractAttribute` `Name` to be MyObjectDataContract{0} works.